# Proofs or counterexamples of composing of shrinking maps

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X,d_{X})$ be a distance space and $f,g\colon X\longrightarrow X$ non-constant maps such that $g^{2}=g,f^{2}=f$. Assume that
$$
d_{X}(fg(x),fg(y))\leq d_{X}(f(x),f(y))\leq d_{X}(x,y)
$$for any $x,y\in X$. Then, is $g$ a distance-decreasing map? For example let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $f=s\times$ for any $s\in \mathbb{R}^{\times}$ with $|s|<1$, then $g$ is distance-decreasing. I can't immediately think of a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be a constant map, then the first two terms are always zero, independent of $g$.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: (+1) Please don't obey that bot. Don't damage your answer.

Comment: Thanks. However, I am assuming a situation where $f$ is not a constant.

Comment: @Mmasa - Then you need to edit your question to include that assumption.

Comment: I have found a counterexample and will withdraw the question today.